# Getting smooth Terminal fonts under Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, fonts

In Gnome 3, the Terminal/monospace font rendering is really bad - not smooth, but thin and jagged.

What can I do to make it smooth, somewhat "blurry"? It doesn't seem to follow Gnome Tweak Tool's configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by setting Hinting to Slight in Gnome Tweak Tool.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the accepted answer which some may need extra pointers with...

## System-wide font smoothing (anti-aisling)

This really isn't a `gnome-terminal` problem but a system-wide problem. The easiest way I know to solve it is with the Tweak Tool. In my case I'm using `unity-tweak-tool`. Install it with:

```
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

---

### Usage

Start it from Dash or the command line using `unity-tweak-tool`.

Click on the icon "Fonts" and notice this part of the screen:

[image: Unity tweak tool Fonts.png]

The ***Text scaling factor*** is only increased for HDPI (High Dots-Per-Inch) monitors such as 1920x1080. The other two fields are the ones that worked best for me to smooth out fonts.

---

### Available tweak tools

To list available tools for your Ubuntu version use:

```
$ apt-cache search tweak-tool
gnome-shell-extension-autohidetopbar - GNOME shell automatic topbar hider
gnome-shell-extension-suspend-button - Gnome-shell extension to modify the suspend/shutdown buttons
gnome-shell-extensions-gpaste - GPaste extension for GNOME Shell
gnome-tweak-tool - tool to adjust advanced configuration settings for GNOME
unity-tweak-tool - configuration tool for the Unity desktop environment
```